# How do I signal the end of standard input in a python shell without logging out of the shell?

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

I preferred using Ctrl+D and relogging into the Python shell and using up-arrow key to load the history. 
But,getting into the Django shell, I couldn't even use the up-arrow key to load the commands used earlier and need to retype the whole thing.
So, is there a way to handle this? 
Something like 'set -o ignoreeof' in Unix

Comment: This doesn't answer your question ,but I'm going to offer the advice anyway: Get out of the habit of using history to preserve your commands.  Put them in a file and execute the file, or redirect input from the file.  Command history in my experience leads to a lot of needless copy-pasting and floundering with history.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Still wish there could be a more practical way.